# Angular CLI production build adds head tag

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-cli

I noticed a difference in the generated `index.html` when I run `ng build` Angular CLI command for different environments.

`ng build --prod` automatically adds `<head>` tag and wraps around the CSS files. For example:

```
<head><link href="styles.262f2f78eb9bad7429de.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/><link href="main.262f2f78eb9bad7429de.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/></head><script type="text/javascript" src="inline.37ebee07daad70e0c3aa.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.209d30935bb7ce96dbfd.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.e7cc1c2675feedf2a4bc.bundle.js"></script>
```

`ng build --dev` doesn't add any extra HTML tags and just outputs a list of generated CSS and JS files.

I am wondering whether this is by design. How can I avoid the `<head>` tag when I build in production mode?

I had a look at https://angular.io/cli/build doc, but it didn't seem to say much about this issue.

Update with some more explanations:

The Angular generated files are injected on the server side which is a .NET app.

Following line is used to add the scripts and style sheets onto the template

`@Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/dist/index.html")))`

I know I can do a string replace right here but I was hoping for a different approach if it could be done on the Angular side.

Comment: May you explain why do you need to avoid head tag?

Comment: @magos because the server side already provides a default HTML template and these Angular generated CSS/JS files get injected into the server side.